# retrieving variables from a jquery each()

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs that may or may not have a class "highlight" assigned to them.

```
<div id='1' class='box'></div>
<div id='2' class='box highlight'></div>
<div id='3' class='box'></div>
```

I am using Jquery each() to identify which one has the class highlight assigned to it and grabbing the id.

```
 $('.box').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');//get the id    
            console.log('It has the class = ' + id);//this shows correctly 
        }                       
    });

//outside of the each()
    console.log('id = ' + id);//this does not show the id "undefined"
```

When I try to retrieve the id outside of the each() it is undefined.  Is there any way of retrieving it?

Comment: Isnt this due to scoping? The variable id is defined inside the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it without a loop:

```
var id = $('.box.highlight').attr('id');
```

But to make it work with the loop, you need to declare the `id` variable before the loop:

```
var id;

$('.box').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
        id = $(this).attr('id');//get the id    
    }                       
});
```

The issue is [variable scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29), which you should read about.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead do `$('.box.highlight').attr('id');`

If you really want to access that variable OUTSIDE of the inner function used for `.each()` you need to define the variable outside of that function.  Note that this won't work quite the same way for asynchronous calls, but should with `.each()`

```
var id;
$('.box').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
        id = $(this).attr('id');//get the id    
        console.log('It has the class = ' + id);//this shows correctly 
    }                       
});
console.log('id', id);
```

Answer (score 0):

update a variable in the appropriate scope:

```
 var id;
 $('.box').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            id = $(this).attr('id');//get the id    
            console.log('It has the class = ' + id);//this shows correctly 
        }                       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword makes variable `id` local to the function. Try just saying `id = ...`

Comment: It's always a good idea to use `var id` in the scope in which you intend to use `id`; otherwise you're effectively declaring a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope in javascript is by function, so when you declare that variable inside the `.each(function() { var id; })` it is only accessible there.  If you want it to be accessible outside of that function, you should declare it before the `.each`, but you will still be able to use it within the `.each`.  Since it will be more global in scope, the variable name should be more specific then just `id`, maybe use `boxHighlightId` instead.